# Strange requests coming to my Flask app when idling at night

Tags: python, security, flask, flask-login, pymupdf

I've left my `flask\flask-login` application running on my PC overnight.
In the morning, logs suddenly burst with the following:

[image]

Of course, there are no such URLs on my server.
Previous day, I was attempting to install some packages:
`PyMuPDF`, `fitz` and a hundred more they require :

```
Installing collected packages: nibabel, configobj, pyparsing, packaging, python-dateutil, decorator, networkx, lxml, isodate, rdflib, prov, neurdflib, filelock, pydot, pydotplus, traits, etelemetry, nipype, configparser, pandas, pyxnat, httplib2, fitz
```

And then it failed while building something called `traits`

Am I facing some insecure library trying to scan my endpoints and steal data?

It also seems to me that it was bruteforcing my login endpoint:

[image]

What could it be? As a python rookie, I'm intrigued and scared at the same time.

**UPD**, preliminarily, I'm blaming `etelemetry`

Comment: Do you have regular security checks running in your network?

Comment: @hek2mgl AHHHHH, you could be right. SentinelOne could be doing that, I need to check, thanks. But the idea behind such requests is strange to me - literally all possible endpoints for typical java\php\python web applications were attempted. Plus those strange login attempts...

Comment: That's the idea of brute forcing and web application fingerprinting